# How to access hidden mounts in linux

Tags: linux, mount, rhel

In my linux box, i can able to access one mount path, which is not present in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab.

I want to disable that mount point. Please help me with the command to show the hidden mount.

Below is the hidden mount in some xxx machine.
/net/bnrdev/bld-views/build

Above path present in bnrdev machine:
/bld-views/build

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by a "hidden" mount. I would expect that `/proc/mounts` lists everything that is mounted. I'm also not sure what you mean by "disable." Do you mean that you want to unmount it? Incidentally, is this an NFS mount? If it is, I would expect the ordinary "umount" command to work.

Comment: i want to remove that mount from that machine

Comment: Did "umount" not work?

Comment: unmount is working, if i restarted that machine, mount is coming back again

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I think you'd get more response on a sysadmin forum.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

These are not "hidden" per se, but NFS mounts found by your system.
You can get rid of this functionality by disabling NFS client services, or just the automount daemon.

WARNING - this will likely break automounted home directories, which could cause issues for other system users.
Please! for the LUV of all things cute & cuddly, make a copy of the files you modify. Justin Case could have an issue with your changes, right as you're falling asleep.